# Ruby regular expressions with html tags

Tags: ruby

If I have a string that is this

```
<f = x1106f='0'>something
```

and The values inside <> can change How would I use regular expressions to isolate "something" and replace the tag?

EDIT:

```
<(.*?)> Pattern worked
```

Comment: A lot of people are going to tell you to not parse HTML yourself. You almost always want to use something robust like Nokogiri.

Comment: @Max it's not really "parsing" but merely extracting a value from a specific tag.

Comment: @alfasin with questions like this it's hard to tell if this is an isolated string extraction problem where regexs are appropriate, or if they've already torn apart a larger document with regexs and string methods and they're stuck on this one part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is

```
string =~ />([^<]+)/
```

and the `something` will be captured in `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex to capture "something":

```
(?<=>)(.*?)(?=<)
```

assuming that after "something" there's a closing tag.

Link to ***[fiddle](http://regexr.com?36dml)***

Comment: Downvoting without commenting is lame!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but for the sake of efficiency, the lookbehind and lookahead are unnecessary here with your capture group. Your regexp is looking for anything that follows a `>` and precedes a `</`. However, this regexp would provide the same match: `>(.*)<\/`. Also, the `.*` would be overly greedy - a `.*?` is safer - or even better `[^<]*` (e.g. if the string were `<f = x1106f='0'>something</f><f = asdf>somethingelse</f>`, the match would be `something</f><f = asdf>somethingelse`).

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox thanks for your comment - I changed the regex (and fiddle) to support the scenario you showed. The reason I'm using lookaround is tin order to have a group-match which can be referred and used later on in the code.

Comment: Oh OK - yeah if you're intending to _capture_ the lookaround than that makes sense

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox I wasn't sure but that's what I understood from "use regular expressions to isolate "something" and replace the tag?"

Comment: Yeah I think you might be right. The wording of the question could have been better, but re-reading it I think the OP was indeed looking for something to grab the <f...> part of the string and "isolate" meant "exclude".